# System of sequences

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, matrices

How can I solve this system of two sequences,

$$
\begin{cases}
a_{n+1}=0.9a_n+0.3b_n \\
b_{n+1}=0.1a_n+0.7b_n
\end{cases}
$$

with $(a_1,b_1)=(1000,1000)$
using matrix ?

I know the answer is $(1500,500)$ but it not gives me the method. I seek a bit on the net but I haven't find good key words to seek this.

EDIT: What I get with the comments and the hint:

$$\binom{a_{n}}{b_{n}}=\begin{pmatrix} 0.9 & 0.3 \\ 0.1 & 0.7 \end{pmatrix}^{n-1} \binom{a_1}{b_1} $$

So because the eigenvalues are $1$ and $0.6$ then $$\binom{a_{n}}{b_{n}}=P\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0.6 \end{pmatrix}^{n-1}P^{-1} \binom{a_1}{b_1} $$

I just need to get the matrix $P$ and take the limit. Is that correct?

Comment: The answer to what is $(1500,500)$? I know how to find the sequences, but not using matrices and I also don't know what you mean by the answer is  $(1500,500)$.

Comment: @wythagoras  I believe the OP is asking for the limiting value.

Comment: Hint:  diagonalize the matrix.  That is, write it as $SJS^{-1}$ where $J$ is diagonal.  Then it is easy to multiply $S^{-1}\times \{1000,1000\}$ and multiplying by $J^{large}$ is likewise straightforward (one eigenvalue is $1$, the other is $.6$).  Then multiply by $S$ to read off the answer.

Comment: @lulu why are you seeking for an eigenvalue of one?

Comment: Not seeking anything.  The characteristic polynomial for your recursion matrix is $x^2-1.6x+.6$ and the eigenvalues are $\{1,.6\}$.

Comment: The reason I pointed out the eigenvalues was to make it clear how easy it was to multiply by a huge power of the diagonal matrix $J$.  Indeed, $J^{\infty}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: @lulu how can I find the matrix S ? (I haven't do maths for 8 months)

Comment: Well, wolfram alpha can diagonalize matrices so that's one way.  I'm lazy so I did it that way, you get $S=\begin{bmatrix}{.948683 \;\;\; -.707107 \\ .316228  \;\; \;.707107}\end{bmatrix}$ .  But it's good to learn how to do it...you can find lots of online discussions, eg. http://www.sosmath.com/matrix/diagonal/diagonal.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

You can set up the matrix like so:

$$\pmatrix{0.9 \;\;\; 0.3 \\ 0.1  \;\;\;  0.7}\pmatrix{a_n \\ b_n}=\pmatrix{a_{n+1} \\ b_{n+1}}$$

As you can see, going from $\pmatrix{a_n \\ b_n} \rightarrow \pmatrix{a_{n+k} \\ b_{n+k}}$ you need to apply the matrix $k$ times. However, this is - as it stands now - quite involved. But now remember that if you're dealing with a diagonal matrix, then multiplying together $k$ of those diagonal matrices is the same as raising it to the $k$th power.

That should get you going. If not, let me know.

EDIT: If you have a diagonal matrix $A$, applying it to some vector $v$ is the same as just multiplying the vector by some scalar $\lambda$ (one for each eigenvalue), like this: $Av=\lambda v$. So if you do it a second time you get $AAv=\lambda^2v$. This is the reason why if we want to apply a matrix $k$ times, we can just raise it to the power of $k$, so $AAA...k$ times $=A^k$, which means that the individual entries in the matrix are raised to the $k$th power.

Comment: I don't understand what you said about diagonal matrices :/

Comment: @Shadock See edit, hope that helps.